# Cash drawer working , if possible schematic

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic

[image]Can anyone tell me as to how the cash drawer works? A schematic would be helpful too if anyone can find it!

This circuit will work after adjusting the resistance and adding diode for reverse current.

Comment: If the cash drawer is working then whats the problem? - being more serious please include the reference to the type of cash drawer, any schematics you have. and why the mosfet tag? you need to give far more information for any help

Comment: Similar question from OP with more information (!): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431538/cash-drawer-regulated-to-mosfet (it was also closed). Sounds like OP just needs a flyback diode across the solenoid coil to be happy.

Comment: cash drawer circuit is working, if any want know. let me know.

Answer (score 5):

It's a solenoid. The ones I've seen require either 12V or 24V, for a pulse of about 500ms. Current draw about 2A.

Comment: can we reduce the pulse for 50ms?, if we reduce the pulse for 50ms, what are the changes will occurs?., is that same circuit for 12V and 24V?

Comment: That's a very approximate number. If the pulse is too short, the drawer doesn't open, or doesn't *reliably* open.

Comment: yea true, because we tried for 150ms, it didnt worked, for that only i askd